# How do I change the default behavior of Nautilus so that it doesn't open multiple folders?

Tags: fedora, nautilus

When I'm navigating though a bunch of folders on Fedora 11 I don't want to open a new window each time I click down a level.  I want it to work like Explorer in Windows where the contents of just one window change.

Is there a way to configure it to do this?  I've looked through the options but I don't see a way to change the behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open terminal and use command:

gconftool-2 -t bool -s /apps/nautilus/preferences/always_use_browser true

or

gconftool-2 -t bool -s /apps/nautilus/preferences/always_use_browser false

to switch it back

Answer (score 6):

The GUI way to do what ricbax suggested :

1. Open a Nautilus window
2. Got to Edit -> Preferences, Open the "Behavior" tab
3. Select "Always open in browser windows"

Not as awesome as using gconftool from the command line, but it is just as effective.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  You can middle click to get that behavior.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not changing "the default behavior" though.